# Java7 Multi-catch Exception handling

Tags: java, exception, multi-catch

I have this code to catch multiple exceptions. I am using Java 7 latest version 1.7.0_51

```
import jxl.write.*;
import java.io.IOException;

try{ //some code       
   } catch (IOException | WriteException e)
   {
    Logger.error(e.getMessage());
   }
```

This gives the error:

```
play.exceptions.TemplateExecutionException: java.lang.VerifyError cannot be cast to 

    java.lang.Exception
        at play.templates.BaseTemplate.throwException(BaseTemplate.java:86)
        at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:257)
        at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:267)
        at play.templates.Template.render(Template.java:26)
        at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.render(GroovyTemplate.java:187)
        at play.mvc.results.RenderTemplate.<init>(RenderTemplate.java:24)
        at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:660)
        at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:640)
        at play.mvc.Controller.render(Controller.java:695)
```

Both exceptions are extending from Exception class. Any idea what is the cause for this?

Comment: There's not enough information here to tell specifically what's happening; can you post the code for the `BaseTemplate` class? (It looks like it's in the Play framework, but Eclipse or NetBeans should be able to get it for you.) It appears that Play has a bug in some exception handling or translation.

Comment: i agree .. looks to me there's a TemplateExecutionException hanging somewhere..!

Comment: the exception stack trace does not belong to the code shown. please provide full code

Comment: (The `VerifyError`, by the way, is an indication of a binary-level class file incompatibility. I suggest making sure that your runtime environment is using the latest JVM.)

Comment: [VerifyError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/VerifyError.html) is, well, an [Error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html). An Error is not an Exception (though both are [Throwable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html))

Comment: It is Play 1.2.4 framework. The stack trace belongs to the code shown. I removed the multi catch exception handling and used normal exception handling in java 6. It works fine, but multi catch is failing.

Comment: A VerifyError sounds like there is some bytecode rewriting that is being performed, and causing trouble at class loading time. Does this happen as soon as the class is loaded? What happens if you run it with the `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` switch?